# SFDX Plugin Development tutorial

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I am following this tutorial: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_plugins.meta/sfdx_cli_plugins/cli_plugins_generate_scaffold.htm

I have followed in exactly down as far is the command

```
bin/run hello:org -h
```

But, unfortunately, this results in `Error: command hello:org not found`

Has anyone else run into this issue?
As far as I can tell, all files have been generated, `src/commands/hello/org.ts` exists.

Comment: try the command with "." added in the start. something like " .\bin\run hello:org -h". reference : https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate/issues/50

Comment: If that doesn't work try workaround mentioned in https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate/issues/74.

Comment: Wow. Salesforce know that they have a captive audience if they can get away with such incredibly shoddy development tools. (SFDX is SO buggy)  @Kalpana if you post your solution as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks! @NickJ I have posted the same thing as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command with "." added in the start.
something like " .\bin\run hello:org -h".

Reference : https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate/issues/50

If that doesn't work try workaround mentioned in [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-generate/issues/74)

Thanks!